# Firefox interpreting PDF attachment as HTML

Tags: html, firefox, pdf

So I have almost finished this, but just stumbled across an issue in Firefox. Basically, on a button click, I am dynamically generating a PDF document and sending it back to the user, in the response. I do this by setting the mime type, etc. Here is the code:

```
String mimeType = "application/pdf";
res.setContentType(mimeType);
res.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\""+fileName+".pdf\"");
```

In Chrome, I get the desired outcome:

[image: Chrome download screenie]

However in Firefox, this appears:

[image: Firefox download screenie]

And when I try to open it, it looks like this:[image]

Now to my mind, this is Chrome trying to interpret the PDF document as a HTML document. Can anyone think of a reason why this might happen with Firefox, and any way around it?

**Edit**

I've added a screenshot of the headers and I find something very interesting. It appears that the content type is staying as HTML, even when I explicitly change it to PDF?

[image]

Comment: This is not programming-related and belongs on http://superuser.com/

Comment: I thought there may be a programmatic work around that I can add in? I'll amend the question.

Comment: I disagree, it is programming related. The only thing I can suggest after looking into this is that something is going wrong elsewhere. I would suggest using a tool like `Fiddler` to inspect the exact headers of the response and copy + paste them into your question.

Comment: Added a screenshot of the firefox inspection output. That has definitely shed some light on the problem, but i'm not sure of the cause. @SLC

Comment: This is not for superuser. It's the server sending the wrong content-type headers.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Agreed! But what I do not understand is how Chrome is having no trouble understanding it, and Firefox is..

Comment: Maybe Chrome looks inside the file, or takes the file extension into consideration. Can you check what headers Chrome receives?

Comment: One moment, I'll edit in a screenshot :)

Comment: You may try adding a dummy argument to your URL so that it ends with ".pdf".

Comment: Okay we're getting somewhere - are you writing this in Java? Can you paste the whole block of code that creates and sends the response?

Comment: It's okay guys. I got it. After I checked the header values in Chrome, and it said `"text/html"`, I figured that it must be being reset somewhere else in the project, and low and behold; some numpty was setting the content type to a default of `"text/html"`. Thanks for the help guys :)